# Django fechas inicio y cierre de sesion

Tags: python, django, sesiones

Necesito guardar la hora en la que el usuario inicio sesión y cuando la cerró, para poder visualizarlo en el admin o front y crear un informe con los usuario que han iniciado sesion los ultimos dias.

He visto que recomiendan django-axes, pero para este caso ya es una aplicación con sus sistemas de login y logout, por lo que podría romper la integración.
También existen las "señales" pero no las he utilizado nunca.

Solo necesito saber la hora que inicio sesion y cuando la cerro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen [señales de inicio y cierre de sesión](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals), la señal [`user_logged_in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in) que se envía cuando un usuario inicia sesión correctamente y la señal [`user_logged_out`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out) que se envía cuando se llama al método de cierre de sesión.

De esta manera puedes saber de manera precisa cuando un usuario cierra o inicia sesión.

Entonces, como necesitas guardar los inicios y cierres de sesión de los usuarios (no solo el ultimo inicio y cierre de sesion, si no todos), es decir un **historial de la actividad de los usuarios**, lo factible seria trabajar con modelos. Por ejemplo este:

```
class UserActivityLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    login_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    logout_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user', 'created']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

El campo `created` es muy importante, pues es la forma de diferenciar de forma **cronológica todos los registros de actividad de un usuario en especifico.** Y puedes registrarlo en el admin de Django y tener un sistema de registros de actividad de los usuarios super rápido y sencillo.

Por otra parte las señales serian así:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_in, user_logged_out
from django.utils import timezone
from ... import UserActivityLog

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def register_user_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    obj = UserActivityLog.objects.create(user = user, login_date = timezone.now())
    request.session['user_activity_log_id'] = obj.id

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def register_user_logout(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    UserActivityLog.objects.filter(id = request.session['user_activity_log_id']).update(
        logout_date = timezone.now()
    )
```

Para identificar el "registro de actividad" de un inicio de sesión, es atraves de `sessions`, si trabajas con `sessions` cuidado con eliminar los datos de la sesión actual del usuario xD.

Por otra parte, si no tienes el soporte de zona horaria habilitado ([`settings.USE_TZ`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ)), no es necesario usar `timezone.now()`, puedes usar `datetime.datetime.now()`, si lo tienes habilitado lo mejor es usar `timezone.now()`.

Y listo, un historial de actividad de **todos** los usuarios de tu web, y en base a la actividad de los usuarios crear los respectivos informes. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Si el modelo del usuario de tu proyecto usa el AbstractUser ya puedes saber la fecha del ultimo inicio de sesión. AbstractUser viene con un campo "last_login" que se debería actualizar cada vez que el usuario hace login. Para el logout puedes usar "decorators" en la función logout.

```
#En tu modelo de usuario añade el campo
class MyModeloUsuario(...):
    ...
    last_logout = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

Luego create un archivo que sea decorators.py si no tienes ya uno y agrega esta función.

```
def registrar_logout(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            request.user.last_logout = """obtener la fecha actual"""
            request.user.save()
        return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

En tu funcion de logout, añadele el decorator:

```
@registrar_logout
def tu_view_de_logout(request):
    ...
```